# How to Create Tables AWS Athena --> Mappings Json Array?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

How to create table Athena(AWS) for Json Array  format?

Example JSON format:

```
{  
   "Tapes":[  
      {  
         "Status":"AVAILABLE",
         "Used":0.0,
         "Barcode":"TEST1217F7",
         "Gateway":"Test_Report",
         "UsedGB":0.0,
         "Date":"06-11-2017",
         "SizeGB":107.0
      },
      {  
         "Status":"AVAILABLE",
         "Used":0.0,
         "Barcode":"TEST1227F7",
         "Gateway":"Test_Report",
         "UsedGB":0.0,
         "Date":"06-11-2017",
         "SizeGB":107.0
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to get output format below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hs1XI.jpg)

I have tried to solve the problem according to this website
[enter link description here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/create-tables-in-amazon-athena-from-nested-json-and-mappings-using-jsonserde/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Derived from your sample JSON, you can create the following table.

```
create external table test(
  Tapes array<struct<
        Status:string,
        Used:string,
        Barcode:string,
        Gateway:string,
        UsedGB:string,
        Date:string,
        SizeGB:string>>
) ROW FORMAT  serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://bucket/test'
```

With that table, you can query all array elements the following way.

```
select t1.* from test
cross join UNNEST(test.Tapes) as t1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your reply

now ,i know  this problem  cause of query 
i think it's a sample SQL query

yesterday, I created table syntax below

```
  CREATE external TABLE monlyreport (
        Tapes array<struct< Status:string,
      Used:double,
      Barcode:string,
      SizeGB:double,
      UsedGB:double,
      Date:date >>
       )
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
    LOCATION 's3://bucket/test';
```

and Preview table  get Output

```
tapes

    [{status=AVAILABLE, used=0.0, barcode=TEST5257F7, sizegb=107.0, usedgb=0.0, date=null}, {status=AVAILABLE, used=0.0, barcode=TEST5257F7, sizegb=107.0, usedgb=0.0, date=null}]
```

I try to query, but it doesn't work

now, i understand query for this problem

```
select n.status,n.used,n.barcode,n.gateway,n.usedgb,n.date,n.sizegb from test
cross join UNNEST(test.Tapes) as t (n)
```

thank you very much

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I am looking for.